# Using RxJS/Observables in Repl with 'require()'

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

I have been trying to learn Observables using Rx.js and wanted to give it a shot on Repl(repl.it), to avoid setting up my local dev environment. However, since ["import" doesn't work on Repl](https://blog.replit.com/npm), and the Rx.js website doesn't show usage with anything other than using `import`, I'm stuck.

Here is the simple code snippet I'm trying to run, copied from their [guide](https://rxjs.dev/guide/installation#all-module-types-cjs-es6-amd-typescript-via-npm).

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

of(1, 2, 3).pipe(map(x => x + '!!!')); // etc
```

I tried to translate this using `require()`, and tried out various variations of the `map` operator, but I keep getting an error with it.

```
const rx = require('rxjs');
const of = rx.of;
const map = rx.operators.map;
//const map = rx.map;
const pipe = rx.pipe;

of(1, 2, 3).pipe(map(x => x + '!!!'));
```

I keep getting some error or the other with the map operator -

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at /home/runner/AmusedWrongLinuxpc/index.js:6:26
    at Script.runInContext (vm.js:130:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/run_dir/interp.js:209:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

Of course, I do have rxjs installed via npm, using the "Packages" tab on the left. Here is the relevant snippet from package.json -

```
  "dependencies": {
    "rxjs": "^7.1.0"
  }
```

Here is the [link to the repl](https://replit.com/@Manish_Giri/AmusedWrongLinuxpc-1) in case anyone wants to run the code directly.

Comment: In package.json, adding `"type": "module"` will allow you to use imports.

Comment: The `map` operator isn't being imported properly. `const { map } = require('rxjs/operators');` should do it.